# When data can be found, query from another DB table

Tags: sql, asp-classic

So assume there is Table A, B, and C

A and B are from Database AAA, and C is from Database BBB
As far as I know, I can't join tables from different database.

So I want to join A and B, and if nothing is returned, I want to query from C table.

```
A_ID    NAME        B_ID  NAME      C_ID   NAME
------------------------------------------------
1       Paul        1     NULL      1      NULL
2       NULL        2     BOB       2      NULL
3       NULL        3     NULL      3      PETER
```

For an example,

```
select * from A outer join B on A_ID= B_ID
```

1 and 2 will return PAUL and BOB under "name".
but 3 will be joined but nothing will return. Then I would like to query C.

My idea is loop it, but i wanted to know if there are better idea.
And I'm totally new to ASP so if I tag something wrong... please help out.
Thank you

Comment: If you can join from different databases or not depends on the DBMS you are using (Sql Server?) and how "different" it is.

Comment: As Stefan said, this depends on dbms.  If it's Oracle, and you have multiple schemas in the same instance, or if its SQL Server and you have multiple databases in the same instance, you can join across them.  In SQL Server you'd have to fully qualify the table names, but in Oracle you could create public synonyms so you don't have to fully qualify.  If the two schemas / databases are not in the same instance, in Oracle you can create a DBLink and you can still join them, although I wouldn't recommend that for any high volume database.  I personally don't know what other DBMS offer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  ID,
        Name = CASE temp.ID
                    WHEN NULL THEN  (SELECT Name FROM C WHERE C_ID = temp.ID)
                    ELSE temp.ID
               END
  FROM  (
            SELECT  A.ID,
                    Name = ISNULL(A.Name, B.Name)
              FROM  A 
                    OUTER JOIN B on A_ID = B_ID  
        ) temp
```

Comment: C is from other database. I don't think the system allows this

Comment: When you said `hen I would like to query C.`, how were you planning to get values from C?

Answer (score 0):

As long as all of the databases are on the same server (and your login has access to all of them), you can just `JOIN DatabaseC.dbo.SomeTable`, where `dbo` is the schema name.

Comment: This answer is specific to SQL Server.  Also, when you say "Server", that doesn't mean physical server, that means Instance.  If you have multiple instances on the same physical server, you can't just join databases across them without a link.

Answer (score 0):

If your databases are on the same server, you can use a [fully qualified name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to just join tables across the two databases.  Note that your syntax for an `outer join` is invalid t-sql.  You need to specify what type of `outer join` you want... a `left join`, `right join`, etc.

```
SELECT      *
FROM        A
LEFT JOIN   B on A.A_ID = B.B_ID
LEFT JOIN   [BBB].[dbo].C c on B.B_ID = c.C_ID
```

A `CASE` statement might make your output a little more readable, but it wouldn't work if a name existed in multiple tables for a given ID (well, it would work, but you would lose some data).  However, if an ID will only ever have a name in one table, then it might make your output a little more readable.

```
SELECT      A.A_ID,
            CASE WHEN A.[Name] IS NOT NULL THEN A.[Name]
                 WHEN B.[Name] IS NOT NULL THEN B.[Name]
                 ELSE c.[Name]
            END
FROM        A
LEFT JOIN   B on A.A_ID = B.B_ID
LEFT JOIN   [BBB].[dbo].C c on B.B_ID = c.C_ID
```

If your databases are on different servers, then you can still make this work, but you'll need to set up [linked servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx), which is a little more difficult.